# Musical isomorphisms on $0$-vectors and $0$-covectors

Tags: vectors

Under the standard definition, the musical isomorphisms are only defined on $1$-vectors and $1$-covectors. According to Wikipedia, these can be extended to $k$-vectors and $k$-covectors by defining

$(v_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_k)^\flat = v_1{}^\flat \wedge \ldots \wedge v_k{}^\flat, \,\,\,\,\, (\alpha_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_k)^\sharp = \alpha_1{}^\sharp \wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_k{}^\sharp$

where $v_i$ are $1$-vectors and $\alpha_i$ are $1$-covectors. Can the definition be extended to $0$-vectors and $0$-covectors, i.e. real numbers? For example, what are $1^\flat$ and $1^\sharp$?

Comment: Do you know what a volume form/element is? Or even a better question, have you seen the general expression for these isomorphisms?

Comment: Yes, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the volume form is $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$.

Comment: I do not know the general definition of these isomorphisms.